# Vercel Yarn Install Fails

Tags: next.js, vercel, yarn-workspaces

I am using a yarn workspace. All the modules install and build locally.

I've tried:

- clearing the cache
- deleting node_modules
- List item
- Reconnecting GitHub to Vercel (because it appears that there maybe a connection error)

deleting yarn.lock

With no luck.

```
error Command failed.
Exit code: 128
Command: git
Arguments: ls-remote --tags --heads git://github.com/nodejs/undici.git
Directory: /vercel/path0/apps/landing
Output:
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 140.82.114.4]: errno=Connection timed out
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/install for documentation about this command.
Error: Command "yarn install" exited with 128
```